# In Metapost, access the points of a path copy

Tags: metapost

In Metapost, I want to copy a path and be able to address the points directly. I tried this, but it seems like `pp1` doesn not exists. Any idea how to do it?

```
beginfig(1);
    pair p[];
    p1=(0,100);
    p2=(50, 0);
    p3=(100,100);

    pair pp[];
    pp := p shifted (25, 0);

    show p[1];
    show pp[1];

    draw p[1] -- pp[1];
endfig;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` is not a path, it is an array. You have to iterate over all the suffixes and shift them:

```
beginfig(1);
    pair p[];
    p1=(0,100);
    p2=(50, 0);
    p3=(100,100);

    pair pp[];

    forsuffixes i = 1,2,3  :
      pp[i] := p[i] shifted (25, 0);
    endfor

    show p[1];
    show pp[1];

    draw p[1] -- pp[1];
endfig;
end;
```

The other option is to actually define a `path` and then access individual points using `point n of path`:

```
beginfig(1);
  path p, pp;

  p := (0,100) -- (50,0) -- (100,100);
  pp := p shifted (25, 0);

  show point 0 of p;
  show point 0 of pp

  draw point 0 of p -- point 0 of pp;
endfig;
end;
```

Comment: Technically `pair p[]`  does not really define an array either; it's more a collection of variables with a common prefix.  So, for example, you are not limited to using integers as suffixes:  after `pair p[]`, you could use `p.A`, `p.2r`, etc as well as `p1`...